# Where are the Entity Framework t4 templates for Data Annotations?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, data-annotations

I have been googling this non stop for 2 days now and can't find a single complete, ready to use, fully implemented t4 template that generates DataAnnotations.  Do they even exist?

I generate POCOs with the standard t4 templates.  The actual database table has metadata that describes some of the validation rules, eg not null, nvarchar(25), etc.

So all I want is a t4 template that can take my table and generate a POCO *with* DataAnnotations, eg

```
public class Person
{

[Required]
[StringLength(255)]
public FirstName {get;set}

}
```

It is a basic and fundamental requirement, surely I can not be the first person in the entire world to have this requirement? I don't want to re-invent the wheel here.  Yet I haven't found it after searching high and low for days.

This must be possible (and hopefully must be available somewhere to just download) - it would be criminally wrong to have to *manually* type in these annotations when the metadata for them already exists in the database.

Comment: @JK: when you notice that a tag you've used is only used by a few other questions, it's a hint that you've chosen the wrong tag. **ASP.NET** instead of **aspnet**.

Comment: Check this [POCO Entity Generator With Data Annotations](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ace90833-e783-423d-9545-ce8b3b8cca08)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here](http://t4metadatatemplate.codeplex.com/) is what you want!

> **[T4 Metadata and Data Annotations Template](http://t4metadatatemplate.codeplex.com/)**
>
> This T4 template handles generating metadata classes from an Entity
>   Framework 4 model and decorates properties with data annotation
>   attributes such as [Required] and [StringLength]. The [DataType]
>   attribute is also applied when appropriate. It'll also generate
>   ErrorMessage values based upon property names for required fields.

Comment: I have no idea how Microsoft hasn't done this already as a part of Entity Framework... thanks for the link!

Comment: Is there an update for Entity Framework 6? The linked project seems to be archived.