# How to add data annotation for entities automatically created by Data-First?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, database-first

If model-first, we use `[MetadataType(typeof(ConceptMetadataSource))]` to attach a MetadataSource file which contains all the data annotations like  `[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]` or `[Display(Name = "Title")]`.

For example:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ConceptMetadataSource))]
public partial class Concept
...
```

Now, I am using database-first approach since there is an existing database. This time, the entity classes are automatically created by edmx model. At the beginning of each entity class, there is lines of comment below:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Since the code will be regenerated once we modify a table in the database, the data annotations will be wiped out each time the entity classes are regenerated.

Can anyone tell me what is the best method to annotate those entity classes? Thank you.

Comment: have you found a solution yet, Blaise ?

Comment: Yes @reidLinden, use partial class.

Comment: How can I close this question? That answer is not a good one and I already have a solution.

Comment: answer it yourself and choose that as the answer...its a valid endpoint

Comment: reidLinden, I have just posted the answer.

Comment: check this ! http://stackoverflow.com/a/7373371/926460

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, here is the answer.

The trick is, the auto-generated classes are all partial classes. The compilation process will combine all partial classes with the same name.

If we have `public partial class Concept` generated by `DbContext`, all we need to do is to create another one started with `public partial class Concept`. This new partial class can be created in a different folder, but we need to its namespace should be updated into the same as the auto-generated partial class.

In this newly created partial class, we can add all kinds of data-annotations such as

```
[Required(ErrorMesssage="This Field is required")]
```

Or, we can even add new properties like

```
FullName {get {return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);}}
```

If the model is updated from the database again, only the auto-generated partial classes will be updated. Those newly manually added partial classes, which contain our annotations and other manipulations will remain intact.

Answer (score 15):

All you have to do is create another partial class and use metadatatype attribute. Here is the sample code

```
//This is generated by EDMX

namespace DataLayer
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            this.CustomerAddresses = new HashSet<CustomerAddress>();
            this.CustomerOrders = new HashSet<CustomerOrder>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string EmailId { get; set; }


        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CustomerOrder> CustomerOrders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Add following code manually

```
namespace DataLayer
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(CustomerMetaData))]
    public partial  class Customer
    {

    }
    public class CustomerMetaData
    {
        [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "First name must be 25 characters or less in length.")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required.")]
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

define a view model like

```
public class VMConcept
{ 
    public Concept NewConcept {get; set;}
}

[MetadataType(typeof(ConceptMetadataSource))]
public partial class Concept{}

public class ConceptMetadataSource {

 [Required(ErrorMesssage="This Field is required")]
 public string PropertyName {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, John. But the difficulty is that once we modify the Concept table, the Concept.cs will be re-created. And all annotation attributes will be removed.

Did you really write those [Required ...] tags inside the classes generated by edmx?

Comment: no not in the classes by the `edmx`, i have updated the answer, define a view model which will have the property of type `Concept`...

Comment: The second section still add [MetadataType] attribute in the Concept class. Is it supposed to be `public partial class VMConcept{}`?

Comment: What? Do you mean we have to edit the auto-generated entity classes? If that is the case, once we add some columns in the table in the database, the entity class will be re-created and the [Metadata] will be wiped out again.