# Entity Framework 5 - POCO template Data Annotations

Tags: entity-framework, validation, poco, t4, entity-framework-5

I downloaded EF5 which comes with T4 templates that create POCO classes. This works for me (database first) but there is no basic data annotations like [Required] or [MaxLength] that could easily come from EDMX.

My first quess is to edit the T4 template but I'm worried I'd have to update it with every new EF version update (when template changes), not to even mention that I'm sure T4 for these annotations was already coded.

Can anyone point me to the right direction, either to existing modified EF5 templates or other way to auto-generate "basic" data annotations from EDMX model? (and I don't mean Fluent API)

Comment: A little bit late, I know, but the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748619/where-are-the-entity-framework-t4-templates-for-data-annotations

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, I know, but the answer is here:

[T4 Metadata and Data Annotations Template](http://t4metadatatemplate.codeplex.com/)

> This T4 template handles generating metadata classes from an Entity
>   Framework 4 model and decorates properties with data annotation
>   attributes such as [Required] and [StringLength]. The [DataType]
>   attribute is also applied when appropriate. It'll also generate
>   ErrorMessage values based upon property names for required fields.